# how to limit the number of simultaneous processes per user in the system?

Tags: linux, security, debian

yep, i know that question was asked many times, but unfortunately i didn't find the complete answer on it.

so, how to limit the number of simultaneous processes per user?

i  found two solutions:

1. using pam_limits. in that case i need to configure /etc/security/limits.conf file. unfortunately, this solution works only for pam aware applications, that is it's not universal.
2. using ulimit called from $HOME/profile. unfortunately it doens't work in all cases too. i tried to set "ulimit -u 100" and then launched in the same shell "stress --vm 200 --vm--bytes 100". application was successfully launched and i got more than 200 processes under user root.

i need to build a robust system, so solutions which work only in some cases are inappropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kernel security patch [grsecurity](http://grsecurity.net/) has a feature called `Enforce RLMIT_NPROC on execs`. When enabled, it enforces per-user limits to be system-wide instead of per-login (or worse, as you have observed).

Comment: For 3.* kernels grsecurity is on test stage, so we will give it a chance in our next release. Thanks or advice.

Comment: Have you tried it on production servers?

Comment: Yes, in the past grsecurity was a great success for me in a quite large mail/web service. And grsecurity web site tells us this: `grsecurity in the news: Microsoft/Skype run grsecurity on 10,000 supernodes (May 1 2012)`

Answer (score 0):

In the same shell it will not work. Try to put the ulimit setting in you .bashrc of root, login as root again and try. You can verify with ulimit -a to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

Comment: it doesn't work everywhere because /etc/security/limits.conf is for PAM aware applications only.

Comment: Also /etc/login.conf in BSDs.  I don't believe either of these are PAM only, but could be mistaken.